# ECefException: Invalid CEF Library version after upgrading to newer version of Chromium3

Tags: delphi, chromium, chromium-embedded, tchromium

In an attempt to correct another problem, I've upgraded to a more recent version of Chromium Embedded (DCEF3). (Version I had was a year or so old.) I'm using delphi 2010. Now when my app tries to load the form with the TChromium control, I get "Error: ECefException: Invalid CEF Library version." So far I've tried:

- searching computer for old versions of dcef3_D14.bpl and dcef3_D14.dcp to make sure compiler wasn't seeing an older version.
- rebuilding all libraries that use my library with the TChromium control
- updating the packages list to make sure dcef3_D14.bpl was there.
- deleting and re-adding the TChromium control on my form
- making sure the files from ...dcef\bin\Win32 are in the output folder in case any of the dll's etc are needed.

I'm still getting the error. What next? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "...are in the project folder..." The project folder is not necessarily where you need to place these files. They need to be in the *Output* folder, otherwise the same directory as your *executable*, not your *project*. Also, your question isn't very clear which `DCEF` library you're using, whether you have the latest. The `CEF` and `DCEF` are different, and work hand-in-hand. `CEF` is the Chromium binaries themselves. `DCEF` is the Delphi library which uses those binaries. Whatever `DCEF` version you have needs to support your `CEF` binaries. So, make sure they're updated at the same time.

Comment: I should have written output folder; I've edited the question to reflect this. I got the latest version of DCEF from https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3. I wasn't aware that I needed to also get new CEF files (I thought the DCEF had all of the latest together), so this may be where the problem lies.

Comment: Presumably, the binaries which come with `DCEF` *should* work with it. Just gotta be careful with Win32 vs. Win64. `DCEF` may or may not support the `CEF` version you have. Just keep in mind `CEF` is pretty much universal binaries, which can be imported into other languages than just Delphi.

Answer (score 3):

DCEF3 is not compatiable with newest of Chromium.

Use DCEF4 instead at this URL: [DCEF4](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi)

DCEF4 compatiable with lastest CEF version, [Download lastest CEF](http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/index.html)

Warning: DCEF4 component different from DCEF3, please try before use.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that Win32 files that came with DCEF3 were suitable, so that one source had what I needed. The error message was coming from a lingering reference in the requires list to an old DCEF (v1) library. The mix of DCEF and DCEF3 was causing the invalid library version issue.